# Firewall not blocking http and https service

Tags: linux, firewall, fedora, services

Here is the output of my firewall-cmd. The services list doesn't contain http and https 
What I understand by this is that http and https is not enabled. And so firewall should 
block all packets related to it. But I can access website on my linux-fedora box on firefox 
What could be reason for that ?

```
firewall-cmd --list-all
FedoraWorkstation (default, active)
  interfaces: ens33
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports: 1025-65535/udp 1025-65535/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Comment: firewalld doesn't block *local* access by default. Are you trying this from the system to itself?

Comment: I am just trying to block http and https service on fedora and trying to understand how this firewall works. As per what I understand when you have `  services: dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh` in the list that means the other services should be blocked right ? Otherwise whats the point of including or excluding http/https in the services of firewall

Comment: Again: where are you experimenting from?

Comment: From inside the fedora box only. Everything on the linux box. Changing the firewall configuration etc.

Comment: So as told before: "firewalld doesn't block local access". If you want to test your firewall made with firewalld you can use network namespaces so it will come from elsewhere rather than from the local system. Else, I'm sure there are various ways to override this behavior and somebody might give one, but that's not how firewalld is intended to be used.